# MpMovieplayerController tap gesture recognizer doesn't trigger when in fullscreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

I´m trying to use `UITapGestureRecognizer` in order to handle the taps on my fullscreen video. If I omit `[self.player setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];` it works, but then my video won't scale to fit the screen.

From my .m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mov"];
    player =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath]];

    player.shouldAutoplay = NO;
    player.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    player.fullscreen = YES;
    self.player = player;
    [self.player prepareToPlay];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:player.view.bounds];
    [aView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [self.player.view addSubview:aView];
}

- (IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender {
    //add the MPMoviePlayerViewController to this view (as subview)
    //Play movie
    [self.view addSubview:self.player.view];
    [self.player setFullscreen:YES animated:NO]; //commenting out this will make it work
    [self.player play];
}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"tap tap");
}
```

From my .h:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *player;
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
```

Comment: When using fullscreen the way you do it, `MPMoviePlayerController does not really use its normal view but directly plays on a window. To get your code to work on fullscreen as well, you will have to add that gesture-recogniser once the player switched to fullscreen. You would want to find an instance of MPMovieView within the window's view-stack and add it to that view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my comment, I drafted how to get that covered when using proper fullscreen (`[self.player setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];`).

I would suggest that instead you simply resize the player view to cover the entire screen by setting its frame accordingly.

You initialising code would have to get rid of that `player.fullscreen = YES;`, but that I guess is obvious by now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this seems to be a simple solution to my problem. I just had to calculate the scaleFactor (by width) as well as the new originY - and put those in a CGRectMake() function - works great!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(willEnterFullScreen:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification
                                           object:nil];

- (void)willEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.player.backgroundView.bounds];
    [aView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    [self.view.window addSubview:aView];
}
```

and then remove your subview when MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification is posted

Comment: This also looks promising, ill try this method as well tomorrow to see how it works. Thank you for the suggestion.